# AjaxMin error - Couldn't find the file

Tags: version, ajaxmin

My application was working fine(still in the developing stage). Built on VS2012 with 2008R2. I had added Editor control to my form. This was displaying fine then I tried to customize the toolbar. Then the toolbar doesn't showup in the browser but was fine in VS. I deceided to reinstall the ajaxtoolkit; did it through nugget package. Now I see this error in VS aspx page:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxMin, Version=5.2.5021.15808, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=21ef50ce11b5d80f' or one of its dependencies.
```

This is what I have in web.config:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <add assembly="System.ServiceModel.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add assembly="System.Data.Services.Client, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <add assembly="System.Data.Services.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" clientIDMode="AutoID">
  <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"/>
  </controls>
</pages>
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="AjaxMin" publicKeyToken="21ef50ce11b5d80f" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.5021.15808" newVersion="5.2.5021.15808"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Trying to look up in the web and cannot find any solutions.

When I open the AjaxMin.dll in VS, the product version is 4.97.4951.28478.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I changed the version number to "4.9.......", now it is working fine.